# Group by count multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to find out why my group by count query is not working. I am using Microsoft SQL Server and there are 2 tables I am trying to join.

My query needs to bring up the number of transactions made for each type of vehicle. The output of the query needs to have a separate row for each type of vehicle such as ute, hatch, sedan, etc.

```sql
CREATE TABLE vehicle
(
     vid   INT PRIMARY KEY,
     type  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     year  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
     price DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO vehicle
VALUES (1, 'Sedan', 2020, 240)

CREATE TABLE purchase
(
     pid        INT PRIMARY KEY,
     vid        INT REFERENCES vehicle(vid),
     pdate      DATE NOT NULL,
     datepickup DATE NOT NULL,
     datereturn DATE NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO purchase
VALUES (1, 1, '2020-07-12', '2020-08-21', '2020-08-23')
```

I have about 10 rows on information in each table I just haven't written it out.

This is what I wrote but it doesn't return the correct number of transactions for each type of car.

```sql
SELECT 
    vehicle.vid,
    COUNT(purchase.pid) AS NumberOfTransactions
FROM   
    purchase
JOIN 
    vehicle ON vehicle.vid = purchase.pid
GROUP BY 
    vehicle.type;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't compile as `vID` is not present in the `group by`. What is not correct about the result, please show examples, as that should work

Comment: try `SELECT Vehicle.Type, COUNT(Purchase.pID) AS NumberOfTransactions FROM Purchase
JOIN Vehicle ON Vehicle.vID = Purchase.pID
GROUP BY Vehicle.Type;`

Comment: The two answers by scaisEdge and Gordon Linoff show the two mistakes you made. Combine the answers hence to get a proper query. If you want to show vehicle types that haven't been purchased yet, you need an outer join: `FROM vehicle LEFT JOIN purchase` along with `COUNT(Purchase.pID)`. Please see Gordon's remark on table aliases. Alias names enhance queries' readability. (You can upvote both answers and post your own answer with the complete query and accept this one after two days.)

Comment: Yes I see where I went wrong, All is well query is now working as intended with the answers provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` columns are inconsistent.  You should write the query like this:

```
SELECT v.Type, COUNT(*) AS NumPurchases
FROM Purchase p JOIN
     Vehicle v
     ON v.vID = p.pID
GROUP BY v.Type;
```

Note the use of table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.

If this doesn't produce the expected values, you will need to provide sample data and desired results to make it clear what the data really looks like and what you expect.